# How to reset footnote numbers for each page?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2010, office-for-mac

Is it possible to have Microsoft Word reset the footnote numbers on each page?

I'm using Mac Word 2011 but are there any Word versions which support this? If yes maybe I could figure out how to do it in the version I have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Word 2007/2010/2013 it's easy, open the footnote and endnote dialog and choose "restart at each page". See the OP's comment below for the Mac Word 2011 instructions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! For others who use Mac Word 2011, the way to access this window is by going in the 'Insert' menu (in the menu bar) and then 'Footnote...'

Comment: I missed that you were using Mac Word, sorry!